# C++ in Qt array not allowing values to be passed in or operated on

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

This class will compile fine and run in visual studios, and it will compile in Qt, but when the array is actually used in the `==` operator in `createItem()` it is errored out. It says `segmentation fault` when running. I have tried setting values into the array manually and it doesnt work either. Does Qt not accept C++ arrays, because this class works fine in visual studios compiling and running.

Also I'm a beginner who is just going with what works, this code is probably neither efficient nor memory saving or clean it just does what I want it to for now. But any improvements you may have are welcome.

```
#include "inventory.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

inventory::inventory()
{
}


int inv[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
std::string itemName[1000] = {};

void inventory::setItem(int x) {
if (checkItem(x) == true) {
    for (int f = 0; f < 10 && f >= 0; ++f) {
        if (inv[f] == 0) {
            inv[f] = x;
            std::cout << "You have placed " << getItemName(x) << " in  your inventory." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (f == 9 && inv[f] != 0) {
            std::cout << "You have no more inventory space." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "Item doesn't exist." << std::endl;
}
}

std::string inventory::getItemName(int x) {
std::string g = itemName[x];
return g;
}

void inventory::createItem(std::string y) {
bool exist = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if (itemName[i] == y) {
        exist = true;
        break;
    }
}
for (int x = 1; x <= 1000; x++) {
    if (itemName[x] == "") {
        if (exist == false) {
            itemName[x] = y;
            break;
        }
        else if (exist == true) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Item already exists" << std::endl;
            break;
        } 
    }
}
}

int inventory::getItemID(std::string y) {
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; ++i) {
    if (itemName[i] == y) {
        return i;
    }
    else if (i == 1000 && itemName[i] != y) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Item not found" << std::endl;
        return 1001;
    }
}
}

bool inventory::checkItem(int x) {
if (itemName[x] != "") {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}

int inventory::checkInv(int x) {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (inv[i] == x) {
        std::cout << "Item is in your inventory." << std::endl;
        return true;
        break;
    }
    else if (inv[i] == 9 && inv[9] != x) {
        std::cout << "You don't have the required item in your inventory." << std::endl;
        return false;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with Qt being wrong and Visual Studio being correct.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
```

Arrays are indexed from 0 to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of elements.  Therefore the valid indices of the itemName array is 0 to 999.

Look at your loops -- you are accessing `itemName[i]`.  What happens when `i` is 1000?  You are now accessing `itemName[1000]`, which is out of bounds.

The solution to this loop (and others) is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
```

You also make the same error in non-looping code, like this:

```
else if (i == 1000 && itemName[i] != y)
```

Again, you're accessing itemName[1000], which is out of bounds.

Also, when you make mistakes like this, the program will exhibit `undefined behavior`.  This means the program may run, may crash, may run today and crash tomorrow, may run for years and all of a sudden crash one day.

So saying that it runs ok with one compiler and not another means that you need to fix your program, and not be fooled into thinking there is something wrong with the compiler that built the "crashing" version of the program.

Comment: Never meant to say that it was a compiler issue, but QT must have accessed it differently because 24/24 times it did this on QT and 0/alot it happened on visual studio upon run time. Do they run differently after being compiled?

Comment: As stated, when you make an out of bounds array access, *anything* can happen.  It just so happens that the illegal access didn't affect any noticeable part of the program for Visual Studio.  However, if you changed that program, maybe Visual Studio would start to crash.  My suggestion is not to waste time in figuring out why Visual Studio didn't crash -- if the code makes an illegal access, the code is broken, even if the program "works".